# Can I open an HTTP address with PHP without using cURL or similar?

Tags: php, http

Does PHP have any native tool to open a page like `http://example.com/a.rb?A=4` and then get the response as text?

Comment: That would be `file_get_contents()`. Have you heard of something called Google?

Comment: `file_get_contents()`, but only if your settings permit

Comment: Mark Baker, and if not?

Comment: If settings prevent you using the non-CURL approach, then ... use CURL? Is there an actual reason why you don't want to?

Comment: I had a problem with cURL, and I was wondering if there is a different way.

Comment: @user3505444 - If you can't use `file_get_contents()`, then you use curl.... PHP provides you with the one native alternative, not several.... if you have problems with curl, consider using a wrapper like guzzle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned you can use either:

```
$var = file_get_contents("http://google.com");
```

or you can use curl:

```
<?php
    // create curl resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");

    //return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // $output contains the output string
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
```

?>

I copied the curl example from: http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php

Answer (score 2):

you can use file_get_contents() but i think curl is the best way.

and this a nice PHP Class you must know http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/